# How to sort contacts using Contacts with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, cncontact

I've read official apple documentation about sorting contacts, although I am not sure how to implement it.
So, here is fetch request:

```
let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
```

and my prefered sort order:

```
let sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.UserDefault
```

and this is how I usually fetch contacts:

```
    do {
        try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (let contact, let stop) -> Void in
                self.contacts.append(contact)
        })
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Now what should I do with `sortOrder`? Where and should I include in my whole fetching process?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Updated For Swift 4.0**

```
let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor, CNContactFamilyNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor, CNContactMiddleNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor, CNContactEmailAddressesKey as CNKeyDescriptor,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as CNKeyDescriptor])

        fetchRequest.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.userDefault

        let store = CNContactStore()

        do {
            try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (contact, stop) -> Void in
              //  print(contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value ?? "not found")

            })
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

**Old Version** 
write like this

```
 fetchRequest.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.UserDefault
```

after fetchRequest object created 
so your final output is like

```
let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)

fetchRequest.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.UserDefault

 do {
        try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (let contact, let stop) -> Void in
                self.contacts.append(contact)
        })
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: I've hit my daily upvote limit but this is correct, thanks. Just removed the space between `CNContactSortOrder.` and `UserDefault`.

Comment: O this answer is so great!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [SwiftyContacts](https://github.com/satishbabariya/SwiftyContacts), you can pass in the sort option in the `fetchContacts(..)` request, see below:

```
import SwiftyContacts

fetchContacts(ContactsSortorder: .givenName) { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let contacts):
        print(contacts)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```