# How to sort an Array with conditions in Swift 3

Tags: swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm having an `Array` of `CNContact`. I need them to be sorted by name to have `tableView` sections sorted by name.

```
var sortedContactsDictionary: [String: [CNContact]] = [:]
var alphabeticSortedContacts: [CNContact] = []

func setAlphabeticOrderOfContacts(_ contact: CNContact) {
    var name = ""
    if contact.familyName != "" {
        name = contact.familyName.lowercaseFirst
    } else {
        name = contact.givenName.lowercaseFirst
    }

    let currentLetter = name.characters.first

    if self.lastProcessedLetter == nil || self.lastProcessedLetter == currentLetter {
        self.alphabeticSortedContacts.append(contact)
    } else {
        self.alphabeticSortedContacts.removeAll()
        self.alphabeticSortedContacts.append(contact)
    }

    self.lastProcessedLetter = currentLetter

    if let letter = currentLetter {
        self.sortedContactsDictionary["\(letter)"] = self.alphabeticSortedContacts
    }
}
```

But my problem is, that some of the `familyName` values contain special character like `(` as the first character.

Since the `[CNContact]` is already sorted, the special character names are sorted where I don't need them and if I do something like this:

```
let specialCharactersRemoved = name.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")
let currentLetter = specialCharactersRemoved.characters.first
```

My sections aren't in order anymore. I have the "second letter" of the name (after `(`) for example as first letter of the sections instead of the desired `A` and if I sort the dictionary again, I have multiple times a section with (f.e.) the key `S`.

What am I missing or what would be a better approach to sort the `[CNContact]` into `[String: [CNContact]]`? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with family name starts with "(" ?

Comment: For example one of my contacts works at Andorfine Records and in one of my old phones his family name was (Andorfine Records) (and still is now). I know, that that is not common. But I want to avoid those issues form the very beginning.

Comment: You shouldn't deal with it. It is the user responsibility to proper use the contacts app.

Comment: What if the user adds that character in purpose to make it list ahead of the rest?

Comment: Apple's contacts works the same. (Andorfine Records) is sorted into the A of the contact list.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851296/how-to-sort-contacts-using-contacts-with-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-coded my function and now I append on existing keys and create a new Array on missing keys.

```
func setAlphabeticOrderOfContacts(_ contact: CNContact) {
    if let letter = self.getCurrentLetter(contact) {
        let keyExists = self.sortedContactsDictionary["\(letter)"] != nil

        if keyExists {
            var arrayOfContacts = self.sortedContactsDictionary["\(letter)"]
            arrayOfContacts?.append(contact)
            self.sortedContactsDictionary["\(letter)"] = arrayOfContacts
        } else {
            var arrayOfContacts = [CNContact]()
            arrayOfContacts.append(contact)
            self.sortedContactsDictionary["\(letter)"] = arrayOfContacts
        }
    }
}

func getCurrentLetter(_ contact: CNContact) -> Character? {
    var name = String()
    if contact.familyName != "" {
        name = contact.familyName
    } else {
        name = contact.givenName
    }

    let specialCharactersRemoved = name.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "").lowercaseFirst
    let currentLetter = specialCharactersRemoved.characters.first
    guard let letter = currentLetter else { return nil }
    return letter
}
```